# Bootstrap 4 equal height list-groups inside card-deck

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I like to make a card-desk with Bootstrap 4 that contains internal list-groups or card-block's (whatever sections) and this sections should have the  same horizontal height.

I tried with **d-flex flex-column** and **list-groups**. nothing worked as expected. **set a fixed height to each section is not an option.**

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7kvktrh5/

Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container py-4">

  <div class="card-deck">

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 1</h4>
        <p class="card-text"></p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some description</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Price</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 2</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some Text</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some description: This card has supporting text belosupporting textporting text belosuppal content.</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Price</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 3</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some description: This card textporting text belosuppal content.</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Price</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: *"set a fixed height to each section is not an option"* -- what about % instead of px? Is percent of height an option, or you want no defined heights?

Comment: no defined heights if possible

Answer (score 0):

I hope here is your solution

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container py-4">

  <div class="card-deck">

    <div class="card border-bottom-0 rounded-top" style="border-radius:0;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 1</h4>
        <p class="card-text"></p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="card border-bottom-0 " style="border-radius:0;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 2</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some Text</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="card border-bottom-0" style="border-radius:0;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 3</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card little bit longer.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-deck">

    <div class="card rounded-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 1</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some description: This card has supporting text belosupporting textporting text belosuppal content.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="card rounded-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 2</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some Text</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="card rounded-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 3</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card little bit longer.           </p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-deck">

    <div class="card border-top-0 rounded-bottom" style="border-radius:0;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 1</h4>
        <p class="card-text"></p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="card border-top-0 rounded-bottom" style="border-radius:0;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 2</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some Text</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="card border-top-0 rounded-bottom" style="border-radius:0;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product 3</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card little bit longer.           </p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: almost, but the issue is when you scale the browser to mobile width. the card-decks are not in the right order. you know what i mean?